# Python Time based rotating file handler for logging

Tags: windows, python-2.7, logging

While using time based rotating file handler.Getting error

```
  os.rename('logthred.log', dfn)
  WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it
  is being used by another process
```

config :

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=timedRotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=timedRotatingFormatter

[formatter_timedRotatingFormatter]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s.%(functionname)s:%(lineno)d %
(output)s
datefmt=%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[handlers]
keys=timedRotatingFileHandler

[handler_timedRotatingFileHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=timedRotatingFormatter
args=('D:\\log.out', 'M', 2, 0, None, False, False)
```

Want to achieve time based rotating file handler and multiple process can write same log file.In python,I didn't find any thing which can help to resolve this issue.

I have read discussion on this issue ([python issues](http://bugs.python.org/issue4749)).

Any suggestion which can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found the solution** : Problem in Python 2.7 whenever we create child Process then file handles of parent process also inherited by child process so this is causing error. We can block this inheritance using this code.

```
import sys
from ctypes import windll
import msvcrt
import __builtin__

if sys.platform == 'win32':

    __builtin__open = __builtin__.open

    def __open_inheritance_hack(*args, **kwargs):
        result = __builtin__open(*args, **kwargs)
        handle = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(result.fileno())
        if filename in args:  # which filename handle you don't want to give to child process.
            windll.kernel32.SetHandleInformation(handle, 1, 0)
        return result

   __builtin__.open = __open_inheritance_hack
```